# Not sure how polyval evaluates a function

Tags: python, numpy

I have some data that I fitted to a polynomial. My goal is to (i) plot the data and the polynomial, and (ii) define a function that estimates `p(x)` for some `x` in the range. I have done both, but I am not understanding how `polyval` works.

According to the documentation, `numpy.polyval(p,x)` is computing `p[0]*x**(N-1) + p[1]*x**(N-2) + ... + p[N-2]*x + p[N-1]`. That is, the 0-th term of p corresponds to the highest degree of the polynomial.

```
n = 4
p = poly.polyfit(x, y, n)
```

However, when plotting this polynomial

```
xp = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), 10000)
plt.plot(xp, poly.polyval(xp,p), 'r--')
```

it looks like it is actually plotting `p[N-1]*x**(N-1) + p[N-2]*x**(N-2) + ... + p[1]*x + p[0]`. The thing is that this polynomial fits correctly the data.

So, the problem arises when evaluating the polynomial in a function:

```
def f(x_,y_):
F = np.polyval(p,x_)
return F
```

It does not return the value that would correspond to `x` according to the plot (and a value that I *know* it is correct).

What am I missing here?

Note: using `np.polyval` when plotting does not solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def f(x_,y_):
F = np.polyval(p,x_)
return F
```

1. you are not using y_  in f
2. you are using np.polyval and poly.polyval. do np.polyfit and poly.polyfit have the coeffients in the same order? [see here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html#numpy.polyfit)
   and [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit.html)

Maybe you should try to only use np.polyfit and np.polyval and don't mix up things

Comment: This is the answer, do not mix `numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit`and 'numpy.polyfit` or their equivalent `polyval`. I see no fundamental difference in their documentations, why using the first instead of the second in the first place?